# How to index the custom extension content with solr search indexer in typo3?

Tags: solr, typo3, typo3-7.6.x

I have developed couple of custom extensions in typo3 as per the requirements i have, i have to implement the apache solr to my website.

How can index the custom module content/records for solr ? Is there way to add the content to solr indexer ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is example from solr extension manual for tt_news records indexing:

https://forge.typo3.org/projects/extension-solr/wiki/Tx_solrindex#queue

Edit: gist link with the configuration in case solr documentation is moved: https://gist.github.com/jozefspisiak/a5234d61429321c756ae2e2f9ab2de75

Comment: Can you please add the gist of the link to your answer? Link-only answers are bad, since links tend to rot.

Comment: Thanks, added gist link.

Comment: @JozefSpisiak yes it will help me out to create custom indexing for modules. When i index pages using solr search i get many errors, is it because of content type i have taken on pages ?

Comment: Usually the reasons might be plugins on pages expecting to have some parameters sent in when indexing or the pages not being available for indexer for some other reason. You can check in your database what kind of errors are you getting.

Comment: @JozefSpisiak i am getting such error while indexing [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38348879/keep-getting-runtimeexception-error-while-indexing-pages-in-solr-search-in-typo3)